# jquery parameter not passed to servlet

Tags: jquery, servlets

I have this jquery code:

```
var login = 'joe';
var url = 'users/' + login + '/presence';
var data = {
    presence : $('#presence').val()
};
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: data  
});
```

In my servlet code, I would expect to be table to do:

```
request.getParameterValues("presence")
```

However, it always returns null. If I change the url in the call above and manually add the parameter (e.g. url = 'users/' + login + '/presence?presence=' + $('#presence).val()) then I can get the value using `request.getParameterValues`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use .getParameter if you are retrieving a single value.  use .getParameterValues if its an array (such a list of checkboxes that were checked)

Comment: @John That doesn't matter - you'll get an array of length 1 if there's just one value.

Comment: @dcp Long shot but you *are* doing the jQuery part after the DOM is ready, right?

Comment: @Bozho - I'm actually just trying to get the value in eclipse debugger using request.getParameterValues("presence"). So there's nothing in the servlet itself that's trying to get the parameter, I'm just trying to verify that it's being passed.

Comment: @no.good.at.coding - Yes, AFAIK.

Comment: @dcp Where's the breakpoint set in Eclipse then?

Comment: @no.good.at.coding - In the doGet method. It doesn't hit the doPost, which is another thing I don't understand since the ajax call is passing 'POST' for the type.

Comment: I'm out of ideas here - have you tried watching the request and parameters in Firebug/similar and making sure that the right value is being submitted? And try overriding `service()` instead (in your servlet) and log/`System.out.println()` the result for `request.getParameterValues()` there.

Comment: Also, you might explicitly try using `$.post()` instead of `$.ajax()`

Comment: @no.good.at.coding - Thanks for your suggestions. I had actually tried the $.post() initially and was trying $ajax to see if that would work.

Comment: Just FYI, I'd taken your JavaScript sample as well as the call to get the parameter and it worked just fine - it looks like the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: @no.good.at.coding - I also set up a brand new application and got it to work, so it must be something with the particular application I'm working with. Many thanks again for your time and suggestions.

Comment: @dcp You're welcome :) - just sorry we couldn't figure out the solution, this was an interesting problem. If you *do* figure out what was wrong, post back!

Comment: @no.good.at.coding - Finally solved it, see my last response to @Bozho's answer below :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is logical for the parameters not to be accessible in the `doGet()` method, because they were passed as form data.

First, make absolutely sure that you are not calling the same url with GET from somewhere else and you are debugging the wrong thing.

Then see what does FireBug tell you about requests. For example what is the method used to make the request. And what data is sent.

Then try using `$.post(..)`.

Finally make sure there isn't some evil proxy that transforms `POST` requests to `GET` ones.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I think I will try to do a simple proof of concept app to see if I can get it working with that. Then, I can try to narrow things down from there.

Comment: FYI, I set up a brand new application and got it to work, so it must be something with the particular application I'm working with. Many thanks again for your time and suggestions.

Comment: @All - In case anyone is interested, I did finally figure out what was happening. There was some evil doFilter/doFilterRequest code that was manipulating the parameters before I got to the doGet in the servlet. So the parameter was set when it go to doFilter, but doFilter was basically eating it. Mystery solved!

Answer (score -1):

Try to create you data to send servlet

`data : name1=value1&name2=value`

And servet can get parameters as `request.getParameter(name1)`

Hope this helps!

Comment: **EDIT** : `data : "name1=value1&name2=value"`